# Eclipse giving errors in .java file when making android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I try to make a new android project in eclipse it gives me errors in the .java file. Looks like there are errors in the res and values folders too. I'm new to android and I purchased and book on it but it seems to be out of date already, my screens look completely different  [image]

Comment: Hover your mouse over the red underline to see what the errors are. Also check the "problems" view. You likely have not linked eclipse to the android sdk location.

Comment: Also, make sure you've correctly installed the Android SDK and Eclipse Plugin ADT ([docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)), and given your screenshot, the Android Support Library ([docs](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html))